# remove() not working on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched for this for a while on Stack overflow and though there are a few asking this question all the answers are regarding needing to delegate the event.

I have delegated the even correctly or at least I think I have but I still can not remove the dynamically created div's.

Obviously it does not need to remove anything when it first changes, but if the person changes it multiple times then it needs to remove the already created content so it can re-append it with different data.

At present it does not remove and just appends a new dropdown!

Could someone point me in the right direction

Html:

```
<div class="model-background">

    <div class="model-wrap">

        <div class="ubl-section-1">

            <p>Please select customer you would like the PO to be for!</p>
            <p>
            <select id="companyreference2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            </p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.ubl-section-1').on('change', '#companyreference2', function(){

        var costCode = $(this).val(); var buildCompanyRR = '';

        var companyInforData2 = {
            'pocompanyinfo': 2,
            'costcode': costCode,
            'companyid': companyID,
            'version': 'pocompanyinfo'
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Applications/Controllers/PurchaseOrders/submitPurchaseOrders.php',
            data: companyInforData2,
            dataType: 'html',
            encode: true
        }).done(function(data2) {

            //I need to get the references which are within that company
            buildCompanyRR += '<p id="dynamiclist2" class="margin-top-20">Please select the reference<br />';
            buildCompanyRR += '<select id="companyreference3" class="form-control">';
            buildCompanyRR += '<option value="0">Please choose a reference</option>';   
            buildCompanyRR += data2;
            buildCompanyRR += '</select></p>';


            if($('#companyreference3').length !== 0){ 

                $('#dynamiclist2').remove();
                $('#dynamiclist3').remove();

            }

            $('.ubl-section-1').append(buildCompanyRR); 

        });

    });

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: `#companyreference3` lives only in a string at the time you're trying to access it.

Comment: @Teemu yes on the first instance which is good because no remove is needed, but once its been changed it then appends, its at that point its not removing

Comment: @Teemu - it is appended top the page here: `$('.ubl-section-1').append(buildCompanyRR); `

Comment: Then this falls back to the use of the same id multiple times. You're creating `p` and `select` elements with a static `id`, `#` selector finds only the first in the DOM tree.

Comment: @Teemu it does not need to remove anything when it first changes, but if the person changes it multiple times then it needs to remove the already created content so it can re-append it with different data.

At present it does not remove and just appends a new dropdown!

Comment: its created from the data2 from ajax.

That is my issue the id should not be created multiple times, it should only be there once, which is why I want it removed if it exists

Comment: Use  $('.ubl-section-1').html(buildCompanyRR);  instead of removing as you are changing whole html content of $('.ubl-section-1').

Comment: Your code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/sLyrL3fo/ are you getting any erros?

Comment: I can not use html() because I would need to keep reference of all before and then call it. my code is not working its the dynamiclist3 when dynamiclist2 is on change which is the problem, the dynamiclist3 does not delete. I get no errors what so ever in the console